# Changing width of text box in CSS

Tags: css, text, width, box

I need help changing the width of the text box in the slider banner on this page: {website URL removed}

I'm using the following to make the text box appear:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

It seems to be set to a percentage of the browser window width, but I can't find it in the CSS, and it's far too wide on either end of the text and I want to bring it closer to the text. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using max-width:

```
.banner .inner {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Genious. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: No problem @Sj.slo happy to help. And welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other has solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Comment: Many thanks! - Stackoverflow has some documentation available here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers